# Managing Multiple Counters in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intervals

Within my application I need to use of multiple counters on the same page.  Each of these counters will count from 0 to 100%, back to 0, and again to 100%.

I am using interval to accomplish this using the below simplified block of code

```
$interval(function() {
   if (data[counter] < 100) {
      data[counter] = data[counter] + interval;
   } else {
      data[counter] = 0;
   }
}, 1000);
```

The requirements I am attempting to solve for are:

- The amount of counters on the page may vary depending on results from a DB
- Based on events, any particular counter may be started or stopped
- The counters must be independently defined to facilitate unique counting intervals

I feel the best approach would be to create an independent block of code that could be executed when I expect counting to begin and a block where I can execute a stop command.

My first attempt at this was to create a service within Angular.  It worked great for the first counter and solved for the last 2 requirements, however because of Angular treating services as singletons it did not allow for multiple independent counters on a page.

My questions is looking for direction on the best way to approach this.  I've seen recommendations of creating services as APIs, but I also see the potential of using directives.  Does anyone have recommendations?

Comment: This is a perfect place to create a directive. Create a directive called counter with a parameter count.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback.  If I were to create a directive, in what way can it be created to keep track of the separate counters?

Comment: I added an example using directives below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer based on directives. I split up the actual counter from the GUI. So, you could use any GUI you like.

The counter and GUI together look like this:

```
<counter count="counter1Count" api="counter1Api"></counter>
<counter-gui count="{{counter1Count}}" api="counter1Api"></counter-gui>
```

Notice how using the same variable links them together. Check out the code snippet for the full example:

```js
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.counter1Api={};
    }]);

    app.directive('counterGui',function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template : '<h1>{{count}}</h1>' +
            '<button ng-click="api.start()" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Start</button>' +
            '<button ng-click="api.stop()" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Stop</button>' +
            '<button ng-click="api.reset()" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Reset</button>',
            scope: {
                count : "@",
                api : "="
            }
        };
    });

    app.directive('counter',function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            controller: ['$scope','$interval', function myCounterController($scope,$interval) {
                var intervalPromise= null;
                reset();

                function reset() {
                    $scope.count= 0;
                    console.log("reset",$scope.count);
                }

                function start() {
                    // Make sure the timer isn't already running.
                    if (!intervalPromise){
                        intervalPromise= $interval(function() {
                            if ($scope.count < 100) {
                                $scope.count++;
                            } else {
                                $scope.count = 0;
                            }
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }

                function stop() {
                    if (intervalPromise) {
                        $interval.cancel(intervalPromise);
                        intervalPromise = null;
                    }
                }

                $scope.api={
                    reset : reset,
                    start : start,
                    stop : stop
                };

            }],
            scope: {
                count : "=",
                api : "="
            }
        };
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AngularJS Counter Example</title>

    <!-- AngularJS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h1>Counter 1</h1>
    <counter count="counter1Count" api="counter1Api"></counter>
    <counter-gui count="{{counter1Count}}" api="counter1Api"></counter-gui>

    <h1>Counter 2</h1>
    <counter count="counter2Count" api="counter2Api"></counter>
    <counter-gui count="{{counter2Count}}" api="counter2Api"></counter-gui>

    <h1>Counter 3</h1>
    <p>Two GUIs displaying the same counter.</p>
    <counter count="counter3Count" api="counter3Api"></counter>
    <counter-gui count="{{counter3Count}}" api="counter3Api"></counter-gui>
    <counter-gui count="{{counter3Count}}" api="counter3Api"></counter-gui>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```